# Using getStaticProps in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm making my first Nextjs project, and it is a simple blog using the JSON placeholder API. For some reason I keep getting the error that my prop posts is undefined, can someone help me??

I try to console.log() my posts, but i kepp getting undefined as result

code

```
import React from 'react'
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'

import headerStyles from '../styles/header.module.css'

interface Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

interface IProps {
  posts: Post[];
}


export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {

  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    }
  }
}

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className={headerStyles.container}>
      <h1 className={headerStyles.heading}>My Blog</h1>
    </div>
  )
}


const Home: React.FC<IProps> = ({ posts }) => {

  console.log(posts)

  return (
    <>
    <Header />
     {posts.map(post => (
        <div key={post.id}>
          <h1> {post.title} </h1>
          <button>Go to post</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Im not sure. But can you try to move your getStaticProps to the bottom

Comment: Component `Home` in `pages` folder?

Comment: What is the problem? the home component comes in the pages folder by default, it's ithe index

Comment: I copied the provided code and it works. I can see an array of 100 posts in console and on the page

Comment: Working fine for me!

Answer (score 2):

In your situation it will work only after build, so if you need check something without it, you have to use getInitialProps

Comment: Is there a way to get these values??, because, when I try console.log it in my getStaticProps function, it works

Comment: getStaticProps working only in build, so after refresh you wont get another data, because your getStaticProps works only once. If you have some data which are not static, you have to use getInitialProps for request on every refresh

Comment: In development, getStaticProps will be called on every request.